# Async each introduce a delay

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Here is my problem.

I have an array of objects, I need to loop through them and make an api request for each object.

My initial option was to use the [async each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each). The problem here is the api cannot accepts say more that 10 requests per second. I was wondering if there was a way to introduce some delay or some strategy where we could restrict the # of api call we make per second

Comment: Why don't you use `setTimeout` in your function that calls the API ?

Comment: Because that won't work. That will just make all requests happen just as rapidly, but at a later point in time.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "rate limit" at npmjs.org? Many results. Common problem. Try one and post some code if you can't get it working.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can use [async.eachLimit()](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) to throttle how many requests you want to be processed at a time.

```
// Assume documents is an array of JSON objects and requestApi is a
// function that interacts with a rate-limited REST api.

async.eachLimit(documents, 5, requestApi, function(err){

});
```

Comment: If the API responds quickly, you'd still need to combine this with `setTimeout` to limit number of calls per second.  By itself, `eachLimit` just controls concurrency, not rate.